# Foreign Key to single attribute from another entity in Django

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite, django-models

I want to create database model in django and define a foreign key. All the example I see in internet have following syntax.

```
attr = models.ForeignKey(Entity)
```

However I want a foreign key to be linked with single attribute from another entity and not the whole entity.

I have following models:

```
class User(models.Model):
user_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
password = models.CharField(max_length=20)
email = models.EmailField()
........

class ContentItem(models.Model):
content_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
description = models.TextField()
.........
author_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
```

Here, I want ContentItem.author_id to be foreign key for User.user_id and not the whole User model. While entering value for author_id, I simply want to enter plain id (1,2,3) and not all the instance of User

Sorry if the question is very general and thanks in advance

Comment: That doesn't make sense. A foreign key is the ID of an item in a linked table. Obviously, following that relationship gives you the whole related object - why wouldn't you want that?

Answer (score 0):

You should name your fk field like:

```
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
```

because Django will create the attribute `author_id` automagically and

```
content_item.author_id
```

will give you access to the id of the user directly without an extra db hit. With your naming, you can access the id directly through `author_id_id`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the **str**(self) method inside your models class.
Ex.

## models.py

class User(models.Model):
.
.
.

```
def __str__(self):
    return f”{self.attribute-name}
```

Where attribute-name is name of attribute you want to reference.
Enjoy the coding